# Why WinForm Gets Stuck with BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

hi guys i tried to copy some files with this Code everything is good and the app will copy files but in copy progress i cant move my app or do anything
i tried to use thread but its not works i also use backgroundWorker but still nothing the only control that doesnt get stuck is progressBar its works fine here is my code :

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.Dispose();
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        backgroundWorker2.DoWork += BackgroundWorker2_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker2.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath);
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
        {
            int p = (i + 1) * 100 / Convert.ToInt32(fileSize);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(p);
        }
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void btnTarget_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            targetPath += folderBrowser.SelectedPath + @"\" + fileName;
            lbTarget.Text = targetPath;
        }
    }

    private void btnSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        op = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            sourcePath += op.FileName;
            lbSource.Text = sourcePath;
            fileInfo = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
            fileSize = fileInfo.Length / 1024;
            fileName = fileInfo.Name;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("File size is: {0} KB", fileSize));
        }
    }

    private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of `BackgroundWorker_DoWork`? It doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Coding bugs are usually pretty easy to fix.  But this is a brain-bug, that's going to take a while and you can't learn how to write threaded code correctly from an SO post.  Best way ahead is to find out how other programmers do this.  Google "windows forms copy file in the background".

Comment: @HansPassant sorry man im new to C# :)

Comment: Why do you expect that a Disposed background worker should do anything useful?

Comment: @mjwills is right, your BackgroundWorker_DoWork is a bit pointless. It doesn't report any progress, it just updates the UI progressBar x times ( x being fileSize).

Answer (score 3):

You're updating the progress bar faster than the UI can update, for every single byte of the file being copied in a tight loop. You're flooding the UI thread with pointless work.

Remove `backgroundWorker1`, it's not doing anything useful anyway. If you don't have a way to track the progress (which you don't with `File.Copy`), just use a progress bar without progress (set Style to Marquee).

Answer (score 0):

For testing I created a simple winform application with a button, a label and a background worker and added the following corresponding events:

```
private void OnBackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
    }
}

private void OnBackgroundWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    labelProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
}

private void OnBackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    labelProgress.Text = "Done";
}

private void OnButtonProgressClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Could You try to update Your DoWork to this:

```
private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int mainProgress = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
    {
        int calculatedProgress = (i + 1) * 100 / Convert.ToInt32(fileSize);
        if(calculatedProgress > mainProgress)
        {
            mainProgress = calculatedProgress;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(mainProgress);
        }
    }
}
```

maybe You are doing so many updates that simply Window Thread is all the time updating only progress and don't have a time to make anything else?